# How to allow rDNS(PTR) record to point a specific domain?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, ptr-record

Maybe it sounds too complicated, but I will do my best to explain. The problem is the following: some domain is pointing my server`s IP address. How can I block that rDNS (PTR) record, so I can attach my domain to IP? I`ve already blocked that domain in /etc/hosts file like this:
127.0.0.1   horribledomain.com

Answer (score 0):

If it is public IP address then generally data center handle this rDNS entries. These entries are manage in related DNS zone. So check with require records.